# Caching Vs. Query Directly from Database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, caching, laravel-5

## Query Directly from Database

```
Route::get('/users', function() {
    $user = User::all();
    return $users; 
});
```

---

## Caching

```
Route::get('/users', function() {
    $users = User::all();
    Cache::put('users',$user,60);
    if(Cache::has('users')){
        return Cache::get('users');
    }
});
```

---

## Result

Comparing both of these in the browser when page load, I don't notice the different at all.

they both returned list of users of my database

Is there any **tool/way** to show the **performance** of them ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For starters, this **isn't caching**:

```
Route::get('/users', function() {
    $users = User::all();
    Cache::put('users',$user,60);
    if(Cache::has('users')){
        return Cache::get('users');
    }
});
```

You're running the query every time, then doing *extra* work to put it into the cache every time. You've replaced:

```
database call
```

with:

```
database call
save the results of the call to cache
ask if cache has the key we just saved
get key we just saved back from the cache
```

You want to be doing something like this:

```
Route::get('/users', function() {
    return Cache::remember('users', 60, function() {
        return User::all();
    });
});
```

You may not notice a huge difference with caching on such a simple query, especially on an unloaded system with just a few test users. Caching is much more significant on heavy queries (particularly stuff involving joins/relationships) under heavy database load.

Comment: But at least, I don't have to hit database all the time. Hopefully, it is a better. Do you know any link that I should read more about caching in laravel ? I just started, I don't even know to connect it with memcache, and even test my memcache. If you know, please advise.

Comment: The Laravel docs on caching are very good, and give all sorts of examples of how to use them. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache

Comment: I was there too, I guess, I take a look at the wrong Laravel version. I saw they suggested to create a table in the database to store cache. I'm a lil confuse, isn't it the goal is trying to minimize talking to the database ? Am I missed understand any logic here ?

Comment: `Database` / `Memcached` / `Redis`, do I need to set up only 1 of them ? Or `(Database + Memcached)` or `(Database + Redis)`. Feel free to suggest me anything.

Comment: @ihue Just one. In my experience, Redis is nicest.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a quick benchmark using `microtime()` at the start and end of your code section.

```
$start = microtime();
// code
$end = microtime();
// Log $end - $start here
```

But these kinds of queries are not that valueable for caching as select all queries are quite fast. It's more valuable to cache items when doing complex database calculations.

Also, in your second sample you're still hitting the database by doing the `Users:all`, you'll need to return the cached value before hitting the database.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about browser performance, optimized queries are some else you can take a look at. Right now, you just return all the viewable fields on the User model. If you specify the fields you need, the overall performance will increase as your queries get optimized.

On that note, you will most likely never use the all method in production depending on the size of your application and your trafic status.

Just some thoughts :D

Comment: Do you know how to set up `memcached` / `redis` with laravel ?